# Uploading image to server with base64 haxcode with userid parameter in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm using this code but problem is that it encodes the Haxcode in nsdata conversion block I want to send same has code which I'm getting with userid which is fixed integer. Please help.

```
 NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 0)];
    //image.image=image1;

    [Base64 initialize];
    NSString *b64EncStr = [Base64 encode:imageData];

    NSLog(@"encoded.%@",b64EncStr);




     NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:updateimageURL];
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *trimmed = [b64EncStr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];



    paramDataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Id=%d&FromString=%@",100,trimmed];

    NSLog(@"%@",paramDataString);


    NSData* aData = [paramDataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


      [req setHTTPBody: aData];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    if (theConnection)
    {
        NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        self.receivedData=data;
        [data release];

    }
    else {

        UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Check your networking configuration." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];
    }

    [url release];
    [req release];
```

It is making the URL connection in right way but response is server error.

Comment: why r u trimming the base64 string here..?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First Convert `UImage` to `NSData` and from NSData to base64string and then pass that to your Webservice

```
finalImagePath = [imageData base64EncodedString];

NSString *strImageData = [finalImagePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
```

and then send `strImageData` to your webserivce.

While retriving from server use

```
NSString *strImageData = [finalImagePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%2B" withString:@"+"];
```

Comment: Why we exchange @"+" with @"%2B"

Comment: Thanks a lot vivek. You save me after wating lots of  time.

Answer (score 2):

Upload base64 string directly to your server

```
paramDataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Id=%d&FromString=%@",100,b64EncStr];
```

Comment: @rajneesh.yaa i have tried with this also but problem is that ,its not getting right response

Comment: use url encoding of your base64 string

Comment: say your php developer to use only base 64 encoding... not any URL encoding... and then send your base64 string...