# How to send Image in the httpbody for sever with other some parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, post

I want to send one image to the server in the body.and the image doesnt have any parameter.With image i have some other parameters to send.

I used below code for uploading.The problem with this code I am neither getting error nor result.

please find the code;

```
-(void)uploadimage1
{
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_imgOutlet.image, 1.0);
NSString *base64Img = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];
 // NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"data":base64Img};

  NSError *error;
 //    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:base64Img
  //                                                       options:nil
  //                                                         error:&error];
 //    
 //    //do some error checking
 //    http://imhsservices.org/IMHS_NEW/api/Image_Base64?AadharCardNo=369369369369.00&UploadDate=2017-05-25&OriginalName=2.jpg&ReportType=Medical
NSString *urlstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://imhsservices.org/IMHS_NEW/api/Image_Base64?AadharCardNo=%@&UploadDate=%@&ReportType=%@&OriginalName=%@",@"369369369369.00",@"2017-08-11",@"Medical",@"2.jpg"];
NSLog(@"%@",urlstr);
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:base64Img];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
    if (!error) {
        if ([data length]) {
            NSString *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
            NSLog(@"%@",jsonResponse);

            //GET RESULT;
           // NSLog(@"A %@", parameters[@"results"]);

        }

    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
}];
[task resume];
}
```

[image: i am getting sucess message when i use in post man]

can you please help me to solve this ,thanks for quick responce.Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5 and Xcode 12.5 (Obj - C example is also added below)

Using `URLSession`

```
func uploadImageUsingSession(url: String?, params: [AnyHashable : Any]?, with image: UIImage?, completion completionHandler: @escaping (_ result: [AnyHashable : Any], _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
         
        print("PARAMS;- \(params ?? [:])")
        
        let boundary = self.generateBoundaryString()
        
        // configure the request
        
        var request: URLRequest? = nil
        if let url = URL(string: url!) {
            request = URLRequest(url: url)
        }
        request?.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        // set content type
        
        let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary ?? "")"
        request?.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        // Add basic auth header // My API has Basic Auth Authorization, You can change if you dont have in your API, Or add any another Authorization if you have in your API

         let user = "xxxxxxx"
         let password = "xxxxxxxx"
         let credentialData = "\(user):\(password)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
         let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
 
        request?.setValue("Basic \(base64Credentials)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        // create body
        
        let httpBody = self.createBody(withBoundary: boundary, parameters: params, paths: [image], fieldName: "file")
        
        request?.httpBody = httpBody
        
        let session = URLSession.shared // use sharedSession or create your own
        
        var task: URLSessionTask? = nil
        if let request = request {
            
            task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                
                if let data = data {
                    if let result = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [AnyHashable : Any] {
                        print("RESULT:- \(result)")
                        completionHandler(result, nil)
                    }
                }
 
                if let error = error {
                     
                    completionHandler([:], error)
                    
                    print("error = \(error)")
                    return
                }
                  
            }
            
        }
        task?.resume()
        
    }

func generateBoundaryString() -> String? {

        return "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
    }
     func createBody(
        withBoundary boundary: String?,
        parameters: [AnyHashable : Any]?,
        paths images: [AnyHashable]?,
        fieldName: String?
    ) -> Data? {

        var httpBody = Data()
// Uncomment below code if you want to send the parameters with the image
        // add params (all params are strings)
//
//        (parameters as NSDictionary?)?.enumerateKeysAndObjects({ parameterKey, parameterValue, stop in
//
//            if let data1 = "--\(boundary ?? "")\r\n".data(using: .utf8) {
//                httpBody.append(data1)
//            }
//            if let data1 = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(parameterKey )\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8) {
//                httpBody.append(data1)
//            }
//            if let data1 = "\(parameterValue )\r\n".data(using: .utf8) {
//                httpBody.append(data1)
//            }
//        })

        // add image data

        for image in images ?? [] {
            guard let image = image as? UIImage else {
                continue
            }

            let filename = "image"
            let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)

            let mimetype = "image/png"

            print("->\(filename)->\(mimetype)")

            if let data1 = "--\(boundary ?? "")\r\n".data(using: .utf8) {
                httpBody.append(data1)
            }
            if let data1 = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(fieldName ?? "")\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8) {
                httpBody.append(data1)
            }
            if let data1 = "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8) {
                httpBody.append(data1)
            }
            if let data = data {
                httpBody.append(data)
            }
            if let data1 = "\r\n".data(using: .utf8) {
                httpBody.append(data1)
            }
        }

        if let data1 = "--\(boundary ?? "")--\r\n".data(using: .utf8) {
            httpBody.append(data1)
        }

        return httpBody
    }
```

**Update**: (Objective - C)

In your case try:

```
NSString *strImage = [base64Img stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
```

Then convert into `NSData`:

```
NSData *data = [strImage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

and then send `data` to your `httpBody`.

While retrieving from server use

```
NSString *strImageData = [finalImagePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%2B" withString:@"+"];
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265592/uploading-image-to-server-with-base64-haxcode-with-userid-parameter-in-iphone)

**OR**:   *(using multipart upload)*

You need to create boundaries for the parameters and the image you are uploading.

Use this snippet :

```
#pragma mark - Upload image with params
+ (void)postRestApiWithImage:(NSDictionary *)params withMethod:(NSString *)methodName withImage:(UIImage *)image completion: (void(^)(id result, NSError* error))completionHandler {
    
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        
        NSLog(@"%@", params);
        
        NSString *boundary = [self generateBoundaryString];
        
        // configure the request
        
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s%@", kbaseUrl, methodName]]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        
        // set content type
        
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
        [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
        
        // create body
        
        NSData *httpBody = [self createBodyWithBoundary:boundary parameters:params paths:@[image] fieldName:@"profile_image"];
        
        request.HTTPBody = httpBody;
        
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];  // use sharedSession or create your own
        
        NSURLSessionTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            
            if (error) {
                
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
                    
                    if (completionHandler) {
                        
                        completionHandler(nil, error);
                    }
                });
                
                NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
                return;
            }
            
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
                
                if (completionHandler) {
                    
                    NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil]; //Make one NSError here
                    
                    // NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    NSLog(@"result = %@", result);
                    
                    completionHandler(result, nil);
                }
            });
        }];
        [task resume];
    });
}


+ (NSData *)createBodyWithBoundary:(NSString *)boundary
                        parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                             paths:(NSArray *)images
                         fieldName:(NSString *)fieldName {
    
    NSMutableData *httpBody = [NSMutableData data];
    
    // add params (all params are strings)
    
    [parameters enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *parameterKey, NSString *parameterValue, BOOL *stop) {
        
        [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", parameterKey] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", parameterValue] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }];
    
    // add image data
    
    for (UIImage *image in images) {
        
        NSString *filename  = @"Profile_img";
        NSData *data      = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
        
        NSString *mimetype  = @"image/jpeg";
        
        NSLog(@"->%@->%@", filename, mimetype);
        
        [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", fieldName, filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: %@\r\n\r\n", mimetype] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [httpBody appendData:data];
        [httpBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
    
    [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    
    return httpBody;
}

+ (NSString *)generateBoundaryString {
    
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Boundary-%@", [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]];
}
```

Hope it helps!

You can have more ideas [here](https://philsturgeon.uk/api/2016/01/04/http-rest-api-file-uploads/)

Comment: Can you please edit my code and on more thing is please check the image i attached  we are using data  not multipart/form-data.

Comment: I think `Content-Type` is not clear in your request. Uploading like this takes a lot of time. you can opt for multipart upload that's an easiest and fastest possible way i guess!

Comment: can you please try it and let me know correct code please.

Comment: did it for my case,I have to use reference code r which one

Comment: Yes, try it may be this is the thing you are missing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151689/discussion-between-anurag-sharma-and-satheeshkumar-naidu).

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImage *imageobj=[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.jpg"];
NSData *data1=UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageobj);
NSString *encodedString = [data1 base64Encoding];
       NSString * strEncondingdata=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"data:image/png;base64,",encodedString];
  NSLog(@"%@",strEncondingdata);
```

you need to convert image to this formate then you can send to server. and one more is check the image resolution also if image is higher resolution server side not upload so, front end you need to compress the image.
use below code for compress the image.

```
 NSData *unscaledData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageobj);

if (unscaledData.length > 5000.0f ) {


    UIImage *image2 = [self imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(image.size.width/2, image.size.height/2)];
    NSData  *finalData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image2);


    if (finalData.length > 5000.0f ) {

        image3 = [self imageWithImage:image2 scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(image2.size.width/2, image2.size.height/2)];

    }
}


-(UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
   {
// Create a bitmap context.
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, YES, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;

 }
```